# SQL Query - Increase int variable value by 1 each time it's used

Tags: sql

I am trying to update info of all records of a column in a table:

```
declare @FromDate date = '1950-01-01'     
declare @ToDate date = '2002-12-31'   
declare @Numb int = 14814    
Update Users   
Set BirthDate = dateadd(day,rand(checksum(newid()))*(1+datediff(day, @FromDate, @ToDate)), @FromDate)     
WHERE UserID = @Numb
```

Could I somehow make the @Numb variable increase by 1 each time this is ran, or do I have to go about this in some other way?

EDIT: Solved it with transactions

```
declare @FromDate1 date = '1950-01-01'
declare @ToDate1 date = '2002-12-31'
declare @Numb int
begin transaction
set @Numb = 14814
while @Numb < 16809
begin
exec usp_Update_Users @FromDate1, @ToDate1, @Numb
set @Numb = @Numb + 1
end
commit transaction
```

Turned the above stuff into a stored procedure first of course. Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: Have another table that has the current number and update it each time it's used?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I messed up when adding birthdates somehow, making the years way too recent, and since these records are already tied with many other records in other tables, I figured the quickest would be to just change the birthdates with update rather than adding new records to every table

Comment: mysql, or sql-server?

Answer (score 1):

Assign the variable outside the procedure. Then in the procedure, don't declare the variable, just add 1 to it.

```
SET @Numb = @Numb + 1;
```

Comment: I tried this already, if I try adding this after the Update part, it just gives me syntax error.

Comment: You're missing semicolons after each statement.

Comment: It does work without semicolons, just the last part where I'd try increasing the variable. Besides, because I would declare it at the same value every time I would run it I think it would be pointless either way, so I don't think just adding this statement would cut it

Comment: I don't believe it works without semicolons. Show the whole `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I forgot the `SET` keyword.

Comment: Create Procedure usp_Update_Korisnici
(
@ FromDate date = '1950-01-01',
@ ToDate date = '2002-12-31',
@ Numb int = 14814
)
as
Update Korisnici   
Set DatumRodenja = dateadd(day,rand(checksum(newid()))*(1+datediff(day, @ FromDate, @ ToDate)), @ FromDate)     
WHERE KorisnikID = @ Numb

edit: Had to put spaces between @ cause it wouldn't let me post the comment it says i'm mentioning users